# Can someone please fix this? (rookie mistake I'm sure)

Tags: java

I keep getting a "cannot find symbol variable temp" error.What is the problem in this code.

```
public int[][] transform(int[][] X)
{       
    int rows=temp.length-1;
    int columns=temp[0].length-1;
    int [][] temp= new int[columns][rows];
    for (int r = 0; r < temp.length; r++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < temp[0].length; c++)
        {
            temp[r][c] = X[r][c];
        }
    }
    return temp;
}
}
```

Comment: You cannot base `rows` on the length of `temp` while declaring `temp` to be based on `rows`.  Chicken & egg; only one of them can come first.

Comment: I "think" `rows` and `columns` should be based on `x`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want put it like this :

```
public int[][] transform(int[][] X)
{

    int rows=X.length;
    int columns=X[0].length;
    int [][] temp= new int[columns][rows];

    for (int r = 0; r < temp.length; r++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < temp[0].length; c++)
        {
            temp[r][c] = X[r][c];
        }
    }

    return temp;

}
```

Comment: What if `X[1]` has more elements?

Comment: yes, it can be a problem. the correct way is to add row and column in attribute too. so it will be more something like this `public int[][] transform(int[][] X,int rows,int columns)`

Comment: You could just assign each `temp[r]` as you need it within the outer loop...the point is `X[n]` could be of variable width ...

Comment: but he/she want to transform the matrix, so rows become columns and columns become rows

Answer (score 0):

Replace the top 3 lines of code in the method with this:

```
int rows=X.length;
int columns=X[0].length;
int [][] temp= new int[columns][rows];
```

Comment: @MadProgrammer realized the mistake :p gahhhh I wish they would provide more details. Disregard this answer

Comment: What happens if `X[1]` has more elements?

Answer (score 0):

You've swapped rows and columns, and you shoudn't subtract the length by one

```
int rows=X.length;
int columns=X[0].length;
int [][] temp= new int[rows][columns];
```

And then your inner loop like

```
for (int c = 0; c < temp[r].length; c++)
```

Finally, you could use [`Arrays.copyOf(int[], int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf%28int%5B%5D,%20int%29) like

```
for (int r = 0; r < temp.length; r++)
{
    temp[r] = Arrays.copyOf(X[r], columns);
```

Comment: But he'll still get the undefined symbol trying to declare `rows`, since `temp` isn't declared until two lines later.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public int[][] transform(int[][] X)
{

    int rows=X.length-1;
    int columns=X[0].length-1;
    int [][] temp= new int[columns][rows];

    for (int r = 0; r < temp.length; r++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < temp[0].length; c++)
        {
            temp[r][c] = X[r][c];
        }
    }

    return temp;

}
```

Comment: What happens if `X[1]` has more elements?

Comment: If the matrix is staggered, the program will crash. I only attempted to fix the obvious type, so the program would compile.